# Error Netbeans al setear el título en el constructor de un JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en java, donde me muestra nombres en diferentes colores en un cuadro texto. Sin embargo, en Netbeans no me lo ejecuta dándome el siguiente mensaje, en la sentencia `setTitle("Dos Elipses");`:

> Calling methods that can be overridden can be dangerous in the constructor because in the moment when the overridden method is called the object is not fully initialized.

Código:

```
 /*
  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
    Properties.
  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */
 package j009;

 /**
 *
 * @author 
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class j009 extends Frame{
public j009(){
    setTitle("Dos Elipses"); // <------------ aquí está el error
}
}
public class J009 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame f = new j009();
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowCLosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    f.setSize(400,300);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);  
    g.drawString("Hola",50,50);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawString("Hola", 100, 100);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawString("Hola", 200, 150);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawString("Hola", 300, 200);
  } 
  }
```

Comment: Comentario aparte: no es buena idea definir 2 clases que se diferencian en nombre solo por el uso de letras mayúsculas vs. minúsculas. Esto crea confusión innecesaria.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacer llamado a un metodo sin implementar en el constructor de tu frame, debido a que el objeto no esta completamete inicializado, intenta lo siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Frame f = new j009();
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowCLosing(WindowEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
f.setSize(400,300);
f.setTitle("Aqui va tu titulo");
f.setVisible(true);     
}
```

y en el constructor haz lo siguiente:

```
 class j009 extends Frame{ 

 public j009(){ 

  /*Aqui declaras todos los controles que mostraras en la venatana
   * layout, botones, etiquetas etc...
   */

 } 

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ese "error" que recibes, en realidad es solo una advertencia (a menos que lo tengas configurado en Netbeans como un error de verdad) que no debería impedir correr tu programa.

La advertencia tiene sentido. Siempre existe un cierto riesgo en llamar a un método de instancia antes que complete el constructor, porque tal vez este método trate de acceder a un miembro que no esté completamente inicializado, y esto puede corromper la ejecución de tu programa.

Sin embargo, el setear el título en el constructor es perfectamente aceptable, así que puedes ignorar la advertencia.

Con todo, si deseas eliminar la advertencia, simplemente puedes crear un método privado intermediario (ejemplo: `initComponents`) que sirva para hacer la llamada a `setTitle`, y desde el constructor llamas a `initComponents`. En realidad, esto equivale perfectamente a lo que ya tienes, pero Netbeans queda ciego al supuesto riesgo, de modo que no te da advertencia.

```
public j009(){
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    setTitle("Dos Elipses");
}
```

Cabe notar que este pequeño ajuste es exactamente lo que Netbeans mismo genera cuando le pides de crear un nuevo `JFrame` (Menu contextual: `Source packages --> New --> JFrame Form...`).